# Run elasticsearch in container with certificate installed in java keystone

Tags: docker, elasticsearch, docker-compose

I am trying to run elastic search as a docker container locally for testing. In order to complete the process, couple of actions need to be performed in the container.

1. install a certificate to /jdk/lib/security/cacerts
2. install an elastic plugin

docker-compose exits with the following message.

```
user$ docker-compose up
[+] Running 3/2
 ⠿ Network elastic_localnw           Created                                                                                                                0.0s
 ⠿ Container local-es-container      Created                                                                                                                0.1s
 ⠿ Container local-kibana-container  Created                                                                                                                0.0s
Attaching to local-es-container, local-kibana-container
local-es-container      | Warning: use -cacerts option to access cacerts keystore
local-es-container      | Certificate was added to keystore
local-es-container exited with code 0
```

my docker-compose.yml is [*plugin installation is not attempted as the cert installation is failing*]

```
version: "3.0"

services:
  elasticsearch:
    container_name: local-es-container
    image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:8.5.3
    user: "0"
    volumes:
      - ./cert/:/usr/local/share/ca-certificates/           -- copies cert contents (mycert.der) to docker
    command: >
      bash -c '
      /usr/share/elasticsearch/jdk/bin/keytool -import  -trustcacerts -alias mycert -file /usr/local/share/ca-certificates/mycert.der -keystore /usr/share/elasticsearch/jdk/lib/security/cacerts -storepass changeit -noprompt'
    environment:
      - xpack.security.enabled=false
      - "discovery.type=single-node"
    networks:
      - localnw
    ports:
      - 9200:9200

  kibana:
    container_name: local-kibana-container
    image: docker.elastic.co/kibana/kibana:8.5.3
    environment:
      - ELASTICSEARCH_HOSTS=http://local-es-container:9200
    networks:
      - localnw
    depends_on:
      - elasticsearch
    ports:
      - 5601:5601

networks:
  localnw:
    driver: bridge
```

looks like my usage of command is not proper.

I also want to run the following command after certificate installation. Any hint on how to do that will be helpful too.

```
elasticsearch-plugin install some-plugin
```

Comment: used a docker file instead and kept this in docker-compose.yml.  ---    
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./docfile/Dockerfile